# Why does Helm time out on almost every action?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I'm trying to set up `helm` for the first time and I'm having troubles.

First, I've created account with `cluster-admin` role. (According to https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md#example-service-account-with-cluster-admin-role ).

After that I've initialized brand new `helm` tiller by using `helm init --service-account=tiller` and it was successful.

Now when I'm trying to install something:

- First try:

  ```
  $ helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io
  $ helm install --name gitlab-runner -f gitlab-runner-values.yaml gitlab/gitlab-runner
  ```

  where `gitlab-runner-values.yaml` looks like this:

  ```
  gitlabUrl: https://my-gitlab.domain.com
  runnerRegistrationToken: "MY_GITLAB_RUNNER_TOKEN"
  concurrent: 10
  ```
- Second try (as I was not sure if there is an issue with custom repo, so I tried from official):

  ```
  $ helm install stable/kibana
  ```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 192.168.0.18:10250: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

I noticed that `192.168.0.18` is visble on pod list:

```
kube-system   kube-proxy-kzflh                        1/1       Running   0          7d        192.168.0.18   kube-worker-7
kube-system   weave-net-jq4n4                         2/2       Running   2          7d        192.168.0.18   kube-worker-7
```

and that `tiller` is running on the same node:

```
kube-system   tiller-deploy-5b48764ff7-qtv9v          1/1       Running   0          3m        10.38.0.1      kube-worker-7
```

I was told that I probably don't have permission to `pods/port-forward` and `list pods`, but `kubectl auth can-i create pods/portforward` tells me that I can do this (the same with `list pods`)

Also `helm list` is throwing the same error as `install`.

Comment: `Now when I'm trying to install something I'm getting this error`. Please add the command and file you are using.

Comment: @030 I updated the question with information you wanted.

Comment: Ok I will have a look. I am setting it up as well.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46688254/2777965)?

Comment: Nope, I was not patching my `tiller-deploy` deployment. I will try that, but unfortunatelly at Monday.

Comment: I tried what you proposed and nothing has changed, still the same issue ;/

Comment: Notice your tiller pod has IP 10.38.0.1 and not 192.168.0.18. I can't remember exactly but I think you need to do a export HELM_HOST=<proper values here>

Comment: @Tensibai♦ when I set `HELM_HOST` to `10.38.0.1` it tells me that `Error: context deadline exceeded`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that nodes, while registered with `kubeadm init` were providing their private IPs to the cluster master. This caused problems, because master was trying to reach `192.0.*.*` addresses which were not resolved as nodes from it's point of view.

I needed to edit `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` and specify public IP of the node on `--node-ip=<public-node-ip>` parameter. The reload the service and restart it as mentioned in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/203#issuecomment-335416377

Then I registered nodes again and everything was working fine.

Comment: Cool it works now!

Answer (score 3):

You have found a Kubernetes issue [#22770](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22770), where there is a workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1455) and it goes like follows:

> What you're experiencing is a known issue with k8s where for some operations it expects to be able to resolve your node names in the global DNS.
>
> And suggested a work around would be to:
>
> - Add entries to /etc/hosts on the master mapping your hostnames to their public IPs
> - Install dnsmasq on the master (e.g. apt install -y dnsmasq)
> - Kill the k8s api server container on master (kubelet will recreate it)
> - Then systemctl restart docker (or reboot the master) for it to pick up the /etc/resolv.conf changes

As last comment on the issue #22770 there is

> I can confirm that adding the names of the our nodes to /etc/hosts on the kubernetes master resolves this problem for us too :)

, so there is not a fix in k8s coming in any upcoming version. At least from this particular ticket.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was not the issue, but you lead me to it. I will provide proper solution in separate answer. Thanks for turining my attention to IPs!